# How to Graph Timestamps Spread Out

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph coronavirus cases over time, but when I run my code all the timestamps are squished together. I want them to be separated so you can actually read the index and see what times there are.
[image: image of graph]

this is the code I used to graph:
`washcases.plot.bar(rot=15, title="Cases per Day in Washtenaw County")`, and my data looks like this:

```
2020-03-01     0
2020-03-02     0
2020-03-03     0
2020-03-04     0
2020-03-05     3
2020-03-06     1
2020-03-07     5
```

Can anyone help me graph my data with the timestamps being more readable? Thank you!

Posts I've looked at:

[Pandas plotting graph with timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364068/pandas-plotting-graph-with-timestamp)

[pandas plot aggregate timestamp index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101884/pandas-plot-aggregate-timestamp-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the number of labels shown on the x-Axis as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your code for loading the data and plotting

# get the current axis
ax = plt.gca()
# set the number of labels (e.g. 10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10)) 

plt.show()
```